# Does buying Fulfillment at level 100 just do a hard reset on your game?

Tags: succubox

After about 12 hours of grinding it out, I reached level 100, having bought all other upgrades. I bought Fulfillment, assuming that that would be what unlocks Box Quest 2 and the prestige system. But instead, it just said thanks for playing; and when I reloaded the page, it was at a brand new game. Do I have to start all over from scratch and do something different when I reach level 100 instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing more and reading some other information found on the internet, I believe I found the answer.

Buying Fulfillment does completely end the game, but it's more like "beating the game" than it is like "doing a hard reset". If you want to see all the content that the game has to offer, you need to keep playing after you hit level 100, but there isn't a lot more content to be had. At most you can get to level 101, learn a couple extra recipes, and start a new game with Box Quest 2 instead. But it's not really a prestige system; playing again with Box Quest 2 isn't a different or faster game (other than being able to use your recipe knowledge from before).